# Create Common Column and Fill Empy values with a specified No Data Values in Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a spotfire dataset that contains three variables (Location, Depth, and Temperature). Is there a way to create another proxy for Depth, called "Z", have that column start from 0 and relate the other variables to that, and where there are empty values, fill the cell with -999.25 (an NDV) - so that I can EXPORT this table as a .txt file in this prepared way.

I have attached an image to show the table I have vs. the desired table / outcome.

I can do this is Excel, but I am hoping to do this in Spotfire because I have hundreds of Locations and multiple additional variables I'd like to do this for.

[image]

Comment: You'd have to insert a row with 0 as the seed, and then you can do your pivot. It looks like you have already done the pivot judging by your column names, no?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in a Cross Table visualization. Assign your "Depth" column to the Vertical axis, your "Location" column to the Horizontal axis, and your Cell values (i.e. "Temp") to some aggregation (max, last, etc; doesn't matter in the case where there is only one row per Depth per Location) of the property of interest. You also have the option to add additional columns for cell values. Then simply select all and copy / paste to Excel.

The suggestion above will span the min and max of the Depth range of your locations. If you need to span a particular depth range not captured in the min/max range, consider including a "dummy" Location with the depth interval of interest.

For the No Data value (default is "---"), according to the first answer on this [page](https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-replace-null-values-represented-cross-table-some-meaningful-keywords-na-if-string-or-0), you can set it to a custom string in the Properties>Appearance dialog, but you need to be using a late version of Spotfire (7.6+?).

Comment: I will test this out asap!